# Click a button on webpage with google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, buttonclick

There´s a page with a onclick event on this page: https://www.boletinconcursal.cl/boletin/procedimientos
Here is the xpath of the button: //*[@id="btnRegistro"]/span[2].

Is there a method with Google Script to do a click on the button and save the file downloaded to a Google Drive folder or save the file to a "Google file stream" folder?
My idea is to generate a automatic download with a Google Script's trigger (Calendar event)  and save the file.
Thank you to the community!

Comment: What calendar event?

Comment: Like execute the script all saturdays of the month

Comment: Can you please create a chat with me [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/11551468/)? I would like to ask you more about your question.